# How to get Facebook access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

According this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) i tried to send get request to graph api

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
  ?client_id={your-app-id}
  &client_secret={your-app-secret}
  &grant_type=client_credentials"
```

but I am getting an error message

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Missing redirect_uri parameter.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 191,
        "fbtrace_id": "AFBj5BLV5WZ0ZTlT62XuaVb"
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

PS: I dont want to log in user I want to download Instagram images for FB app....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I seen you need a application in Facebook Apps
Now you can see in https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

With example:
You make a application
After it, Facebook will regenerate App ID and App Secret 
**Then Input them to**

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
  ?client_id={your-app-id}
  &client_secret={your-app-secret}
  &grant_type=client_credentials"
```

**Example:**

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
  ?client_id=336055786532989
  &client_secret=46ff578663d95d62fa22f257cabe62ce
  &grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Comment: I dont understand why I need to regenerate app id and secret? I already have FB application.

Comment: In https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/, you need a `Generating an App Access Token`, Because of that problem, it means you must have an application that you created on https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Comment: After u have it, u have error in `"message": "Missing redirect_uri parameter."`, Have you filled in App Domains in Apps?

Comment: I am sending this request from postman app on my local desctop. Why I need to set up some domains? I have valid credentials...

Comment: Because the Facebook app needs a callback for that. Have you tried this parameter? https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=123456789&client_secret=123456789&redirect_uri=/my_auth_callback&grant_type=client_credentials

Comment: Oh man I am sorry but the problem was at the end " sign in the command. I am so stupid. I am so sorry. Have a nice day.

Comment: i get this: Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains